# Asp.net Core Entity Framework Linq where query testing if two bools are equal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Simple question but cant seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I am getting an error on the checking of two bools in a where clause in an EF query.

I have this:

```
filteredClients.Where(c => c.Company == Convert.ToBoolean(keyValuePair.Value));
```

clientFilters.Company is a nullable bool where as the Entity in the DB, "Company" is a bool.

However, Checking the results this is not being processed properly.

I've set the KeyValuePair.Value which is a string "True" and then converted it to a bool.

This is whats in the table:

[image: "Company" column in the database]

and after the query has been executed I still get all my records not just 4.

How do I write this where clause so that I get the selection of only records that have "true" set for the column "Company"?

[image: After running the "where" clause there are still entries that have "False"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can read, you don't appear to be setting the filteredClients reference as a result of the Where operation:

It should look more like:

```
filteredClients = filteredClients.Where(c => c.Company == Convert.ToBooolean(keValuePair.Value));
```

If you get a casting error about IQueryable not matching IEnumerable or the like, make sure your initial/earlier setting of filteredClients is not prematurely executing with a `.ToList()`.